# Convert into array Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

```
timing[:start_at] = {"0"=>"Thu Feb 09 2017 21:02:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)", "1"=>"Thu Feb 09 2017 22:02:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"}
```

i have a hash of date_time and i want it to be like array under hash so i can access it like

```
timing[:start_at][0]
```

i can access it like

```
timing[:start_at]["0"]
```

but i cant access it like

```
timing[:start_at][0]
```

how can i modify it to be a array under hash.

Creating that timing[:start_at] hash from JS and passing to backend and this is how i create:

```
  timings =
    start_datetime: [source_start_at, destination_start_at],
    end_datetime: [destination_end_at]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keys in your hash are consecutive it is possible to convert hash values to array as follows:

```
values = timing[:start_at].values
values[0]
#=> "Thu Feb 09 2017 21:02:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
```